# Push flexbox items to the right on desktop view

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an issue I find hard to explain, therefore hard to search for the proper answer.

On mobile I want the following layout:

```
|.info   |
----------
|.content|
| content|
| column |
----------
|.map    |
```

However, on desktop this needs to responsively adapt to become

```
|.content   | .info |
| content   |-------|
|  column   | .map  |
```

I've tried finding the answer, but I don't even know what to look for.
I've tried a couple Flexbox methods, but it end with the .map in a new row under the content, while I want the .map on the right side of the content, just under the .info.

Comment: Google flexbox `order` - and have a look here, will do exactly what you want - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in [`CSS Grid layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) easily along with a *media query* to target mobile screens - see demo below with explanations inline:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid; /* defines a grid container */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* defines a 2-column grid layout */
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1; /* place this in the first column */
  grid-row: 1 / 3; /* span across the first two rows */
}

.wrapper > *{
  border: 1px solid;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .wrapper {
     grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* a single column grid container */
   }
   .content {
      grid-row: initial; /* reset the spanning rows in mobile view */
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">info</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="footer">map</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can surely approach it via **@media** query rule, such that in desktop layout you have column flow as following:

```
.my-class {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
```

And on a tablet / mobile layout as this:

```
@media (--small-only) {
    flex-flow: row;
}
```

And, of course, you will have to define appropriate **order** parameters as you want. I would suggest reading [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) guide, because of its simplicity and completeness.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I don't really understand how I could do the desktop version in flexbox at all. I don't understand how I could make one flexible height column on the left (the main content) and allow the stacking of flexible height columns on the right (info and map).

Comment: @MatHa Look at the last example with header-aside1-middle-aside2-footer in the article. You can make different order numbers for mobile/tablet/desktop layouts and allow flex to wrap (so content and info take by 50% each, so map shifts to the second row.

Comment: But I don't want the map to shift to the second row. I want to it be on the first row, where content would be 100% height, and info would be 50% height and maps would be 50% height and stacked vertically. The other answer about Grids did solve my problem.